# Why was this time-travel Potter question closed?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions, closing-questions

[This question about whether characters can be brought back to life in the *Potter* universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5494/can-characters-be-brought-back-in-the-potter-verse-via-time-manipulation) was closed.  None of the closers left a comment explaining why they closed the question.

Why was this closed?  It's not asking if the Potter series will be resumed (obviously not a good question, since no-one really knows).  It's asking whether resurrection of a character via time travel is possible within this particular fictional universe, given the evidence in existing stories.

This seems very on-topic to me: asking about the boundaries of a magic system within a moderately well-defined fantasy world.

Comment: The way that question was treated almost makes me want to make a feature request that when you vote to close, you're forced to leave a comment describing why.  Anonymous, silent votes to close are the worst.

Comment: I left 2 comments... The way the question was worded before @keen edited it, it was asking if Voldemort could come back. And the answer to that is obvious, so I voted to close.

Comment: @Oghma your comments were an answer to the question, not an explanation for a close vote. It was me that edited it - mostly I just moved things around so that the giant spoiler was avoided. IMO "obvious" might be a reason to down vote, but it doesn't make it not a real question.